# ODBC 32-bit not connecting to SSMS 32-bit

Tags: odbc, ssms, dataflex

I need to connect to a database with the DataFlex ODBC driver. I made a 32-bit ODBC connection using the ODBC Data Source Administrator (32-bit) (odbcad32.exe) using the DataFlex ODBC Driver. After this, I installed SSMS 2014 (32-bit).

I am trying to add the ODBC connection as a linked Server in SSMS. However, I am receiving the following error in SSMS:
[image]

`(OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MINOX" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303))`

Others are suggesting that it is a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue. However, I'm using the 32-bit version in both situations. Is there a solution to this problem?

Help is much appreciated!